# experimental design in R project

Tags: r, data-analysis, experiments

I want to know of any repositories that contain complete experimental design in R covering basic test and analyses?

I want to take a top-buttom approach to learn step by step through a real project how that works. Do you know of any places to find that, such as an R notebook?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you take a look at the [TidyTuesday repo](https://github.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday), where every week they post a raw dataset, a chart or article related to that dataset, and ask you to explore the data. The repo also contains other resources, like data science books.

Together with the repo, I suggest the [TidyTuesday videos by David Robinson](https://www.youtube.com/user/safe4democracy/videos), where he creates screencasts of complete data analyses in R for the TidyTuesday datasets.

Comment: Thanks, though I am really looking for something like this https://github.com/ferrarisf50/Designing-Running-and-Analyzing-Experiments if you know anything comprehensive like that?

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of other repos like that one.

Comment: something like this https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Vikneswaran-ED_companion.pdf